# Google Documents - remove redundant space charachters at paragraph endings

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to have a GAS that will remove redundant space characters from paragraphs endings.

How can it be achieved?

**Example**:

```
This is sentence 1 in paragraph 1. This is sentence 2 in paragraph 1 
This is paragraph 2 (more text...)
```

There is a space character after "...sentence 2 in paragraph 1". (i.e. "...sentence 2 in paragraph 1".
I want to get rid of it by using code.

**So far I tried**:

```
    paragraphs[i].replaceText(/\h\r/g,"\r");
```

where `paragraphs[i]` is the paragraph I'm checking (looping through all paragraphs in the document's body).

**It gives this error**:

> Exception: Invalid regular expression pattern /\h\r/g

I would admit I have very basic knowledge in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
paragraphs[i].replaceText("\\s+$","");// double `\\` is intentional
```

- `\s`: `s`pace at
- `$`: end of string